# PHP Echo - How do I add text to end of of line?

Tags: php, text, echo

Im using wordpress and I would like to create a A href using a php echo.

Im trying to acheive the following, to have my url generated automatically with some text appended on the end:
www.mysite.com/mytext

I have a PHP echo which retrieves the current page url, but I need to add on /mytext to the end of that url to perform a function on that page when clicked.

---

Ive got `<a href="<?php echo $entity->getAuthor()->url;?>">` which is working perfectly, except I need to append another url part to the end of the echo.

Like :

```
<a href="<?php echo $entity->getAuthor()->url;?>/MYTEXT">
```

But that doesnt work, ive tried putting it in various places in the string, and using the concat function (which kind of worked but stripped hyphens from the output)

What is the best way to do this? Im sure its really simple.

Any help appreciated as im pulling my hair out lol..

Kind Regards
Andrew

Comment: your code is located in a post? theme file? plugin file?

Comment: In a plugin template file, Sabai Directory (premium plugin)

Comment: Have you tried `<a href="<?php esc_url($entity->getAuthor()->url . '/MYTEXT'); ?>">`?

Comment: Working for url, but doesnt add the /MYTEXT to the end... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
<a href="<?php echo $entity->getSlug() . '/mytext';?>">
```

did the trick for me.  I suspect it will only work for my plugin, though (sabai directory).